# See a list of all encountered words

Tags: heavens-vault

Heaven's vault involves a lot of trying to work out translations of words. When looking at a word to translate it gives you a list of related words but very often I know I have seen other words that look very similar but aren't in the related word list.

**Is there a way to see all the words that you have encountered in a big list of some kind, preferably with known translation or current guess?**

As it is I find myself having to just look through all the phrases I've found which is not very practical and even less so if there are three or four other words I want to compare...

Comment: I created a new game tag for this. Never done it before so not sure if the name and info I provided are appropriate....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.

That's what put me off this game a lot. The interface for going back to older phrases is very clunky and there is no ingame dictionary of encountered words with your guesses. It makes the work of fully translating phrases, which you possibly encountered hours ago, much more cumbersome than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's Unsolved Translations and Solvable Translations categories for ones where you're sure of some, or all, of the words, respectively.

I'm not sure if you can confirm translations on your own, without being right after a translation, or going to Haung or Tapi.

But yeah, no dictionary of individual words.